# Rails Friendly_ID Multiple model creation with slug on same field failing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5, friendly-id

I am running a Rails 5 application which has 2 models - a `User` and a `Provider`. I am using multiple table inheritance to show that each `Provider` "is a" `User` (via the `active_record-acts_as` gem). So, in effect, creating a `Provider` with the related fields would create a `User` at the same time.

I wanted to implement slugging for these models, so I integrated the `friendly_id` gem for that purpose.

Both models are slugged via a field called `username`. The code in question being:

```
class User
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id :username, use: :slugged
  # ...
end
```

for the `User` model and

```
class Provider
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id username, use: :slugged

  def username
    acting_as.username # this fetches the parent model (User)'s username field.
  end
  # ...
end
```

for the `Provider` model.

When I attempt to create a `Provider` via a controller action (`providers#create`), it fails, with the error being:

```
TypeError at /providers
nil is not a symbol nor a string
```

The stack trace identifies the problem to be at `lib/friendly_id/slugged.rb:299`, which is the body of the `should_generate_new_friendly_id?` method. This method was called by the `set_slug` method in the same file, `slugged.rb`.

I have created an [issue](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id/issues/780) on the GitHub page of friendly_id, where you can find the request parameters and full stack trace.

Edit: added `friendly_id_config` for both: https://gist.github.com/mindseyeblind/9b78c588f5008a494f7157e72da1de6e

Comment: Can you show the value of `friendly_id_config` on each model please?

Comment: Added, please check it out

Comment: It looks like `friendly_id_config.slug_column` is nil - is that the case?

Comment: `class Provider
  extend FriendlyId
  friendly_id username,`
  
  shouldn't this be 
  `friendly_id :username`